# jasmine-reporters option for Protractor's multiCapabilities option

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I am using [jasmine-reporters] for xml report with Protractor. 
Protractor's configuration for [jasmine-reporters] look like below,

```
onPrepare: function() {
  require('jasmine-reporters');
  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter('../e2e_test_out', true, true, 'testresults.e2e.'));
},
```

above config working fine and gettting the result in 'e2e_test_out' directory with 'testresults.e2e.' prefix.

But when I use protractor's multiCapabilities option,

```
  multiCapabilities: [{
  'browserName': 'chrome'
  }, {
  'browserName': 'internet explorer'
  }],
```

I am getting only one set of report. From that I could not understand the individual browser's result.

Is there any way to generate two diff reports / combined reports for both the browsers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution that solved the same problem for me here:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/60

In your protractor.conf file:

```
onPrepare: function(){
        require('jasmine-reporters');
        var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();
        capsPromise.then(function(caps){
            var browserName = caps.caps_.browserName.toUpperCase();
            var browserVersion = caps.caps_.version;
            var prePendStr = browserName + "-" + browserVersion + "-";
            jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new
jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter("protractor_output", true, true,prePendStr));
        });
 }
```

This will result in reports like:

[image]